# chef recipe for docker registry does not work with AWS ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, chef

Chef cookbook for docker "https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/docker" provides docker_registry for authentication like below.

```
docker_registry 'https://index.docker.io/v1/' do
username 'publicme'
password 'hope_this_is_in_encrypted_databag'
email 'publicme@computers.biz'
end
```

But if we want to use it for AWS ECR then we need to generate login token before logging.

```
aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1 #It will generate login token as below. 
docker login -u AWS -p "password token"
```

but chef cook book does not provide this functionality. Any idea how to get this done in chef ?

Comment: https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/docker/issues/826

Comment: @jordanm Thanks, I have already added a comment on the page you mentioned about a workaround but i asked this question here to get something more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround which i am using. But if anyone have more elegant solution then please share.

Setup your access keys to your node. Add this to your recipe. It will simply login to ECR.

cmd = "aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1"
value = #{cmd}
list = value.split(" ")

docker_registry 'AWS ECR registry' do
serveraddress 'https://xyz.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
username 'AWS'
password "#{list[5]}"
email 'none'
end

Comment: I think you missed some formatting here, this is not valid Ruby code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combo of our `shell_out` helpers and lazy evaluation.

```
docker_registry 'https://index.docker.io/v1/' do
  username 'AWS'
  password lazy {
    shell_out!("aws ecr get-login --region us-east-1").stdout.split[5]
  }
  email 'publicme@computers.biz'
end
```

Comment: It is giving following error -----------------                                                                    Docker::Error::AuthenticationError
----------------------------------
AWS failed to authenticate with https://index.docker.io/v1/